# Alternative for Facebook request for non-canvas app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas, facebook-requests

I have an app where a user creates some object and invites people to interact with it. It's not a game and it's not a canvas app.
I tried to get requests to work probably and couldn't
After reading a bit, I understood that these don't work for non-canvas apps anymore.

So...
1) Does anyone know if this is going to stick? It's extremely painful that stupid games like candy crush are allowed to create requests, while apps that might actually provide users real value can't. If there's anyone from FB here, I'd really like to understand why this discrimination is taking place?

2) Are there any alternatives? Sending a message or feed post are possible but, I need to either a) generate a unique link per invitee or b) get the list of people the user sent the link to. Both don't seem to be an option with messages and feed dialog.

3) Is is ok to just embed my web app in the canvas as is?

Thanks
Yaron

Comment: _“Is is ok to just embed my web app in the canvas as is?”_ – that highly depends on what app your app actually is, don’t you think? Go read the Platform Policies, and check if your app is compliant or not.

Comment: So if according to the policy it's not ok, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook policy indicates that you should not use app requests to send users to an external website. However, an embedded web canvas app is fine. It will let you use the apprequests function to render the Request Dialog and provide a user invite experience similar to the most popular Facebook games.